# Can't use dispatch inside useEffect() with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

i can't use dispatch inside useEffect
as soon as i add that line its shows me this error

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import db from '../firebase'
import setProjects from '../features/projects/projectSlice'


function Home (){

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let projects = [];
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('projects').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                
                // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
                switch(doc.data().type){
                    case 'clone': 
                    projects = [...projects, { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}];
                    break; 
                }
            });
            dispatch(setProjects({
                project : projects,
            }))
        });
    }, []);
```

---

this is my slice code

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    project : null,
}

const projectSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'project',
    initialState, 
    reducers: {
        setProjects: (state,action) => {
            state.project = action.payload.project;
        },
    },
}); 

export const {setProjects} = projectSlice.actions 
export default projectSlice.reducer;
```

I want to push the data from projects array to project array of the slice so i can use it elsewhere but  when i use the dispatch; it shows me this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Can anyone help me with my error , im stack for ages :(

Comment: How did you relate this to the `dispatch`? Error message clearly says that a variable is undefined when you try to achieve its `type` field _most probably doc.data()_. Please `console.log(doc.data())` and update the question with the output.

Comment: the error comes when i add the dispatch, if i remove it everything works

Comment: the type on doc.data().type exist  , i even console.log(project) after it and the code works , i am getting the correct data, the problem is when i want to push it with dispatch it doesn't work

Comment: This question needs debugging. Where are you reading a `type` field, that may be undefined?

Comment: i'm not reading any type field, that's why I am stack, i used this method before and it worked very well, now i want to use it again , it showing me this error. this is all the code i wrote.

Comment: plus one on the debugging. From what I can see, this should be working.

Comment: its shows this code as an error I didn't understand it   `  205 |  const frozenInitialState = createNextState(initialState, () => {})
  206 | 
  207 |  return function (state = frozenInitialState, action): S {
> 208 |    let caseReducers = [
      | ^  209 |      actionsMap[action.type],
  210 |      ...finalActionMatchers
  211 |        .filter(({ matcher }) => matcher(action)) `

Comment: Can you try changing `projectSlice.actions` to `projectSlice.reducers` ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setProjects' of 'projectSlice.reducers' as it is undefined. new error . i don't think this is the problem . because i've done the slice so many times like that, never got an error untill now

Comment: Based on the stack trace you posted, it's trying to read `type` from the action but the action is undefined. How are you defining `dispatch`? How are you importing `setProjects`? Can you add the code for the entire component (or hook) for the first code block?

Comment: `import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import db from '../firebase'
import setProjects from '../features/projects/projectSlice'


function Home (){

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let projects = [];
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('projects').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
     `

Comment: Not in the comments. Update your question please. This is unreadable.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm new to this. done!

Comment: No worries! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exporting `setProjects` as a named export but trying to import it as a default export.

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import db from '../firebase'
import setProjects from '../features/projects/projectSlice'
```

You need to import `setProjects` like this...

```js
import { setProjects } from '../features/projects/projectSlice'
```

[More info](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910) on named vs default exports.

Comment: OMG selly mistake . thank you so much bflemi3. can't thank you enough <3<3

Comment: @DevAD This is one of the many reasons I like TypeScript. It can tell you when you've made little mistakes like this.

Comment: @BrandonDyer oh really. I didn't know that